# How to code a 4x shader/filter which emulates arcade crt display behavior?

Tags: actionscript-3, image, graphic-effects

I want to write a shader/filer probably in adobe Pixel Bender that will do the best job possible in emulating the fill of an oldskul monochromatic arcade CRT screen. Much like this here:

http://filthypants.blogspot.com/2012/07/customizing-cgwgs-crt-pixel-shader.html

Here are some attributes I know will exist in this filter:

1. It will take in a low res image 160 x 120 and return a medium res image 640 x 480.
2. It will add scanlines
3. It will blur the color channels to create that color bleeding effect
4. It will distort the shape of the image from a perfect rectangle into a rounder shape.

The question is, could you please provide any other attributes that are beneficial to emulating an arcade CRT feel and links and resources on coding these effects.

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit too broad question. You're asking for ideas, not a specific answer. That said, other features might include temporal blur (images not updating fast enough), ghosting, scanline timing issues, saturation errors, etc etc ad nauseum.

Comment: The specified behaviors attributed to Arcade CRT in your comment, are in fact an answer, I'm looking for a list as thorough as possible of behaviors of a CRT display, an idea is something creative that a person spontaneously comes up with. I am looking for data that actually describes the behavior of CRT and samples of implementation of filters that emulate this.
If you metaphorically look at CRT as HW implementation of a function that receives an array of images as input and outputs an array of slightly distorted images, I am looking to approximate the results of that function in software.

Comment: That being said, I will gladly accept your comment as an answer if you could add more details, links and perhaps some hints on implementation.